# Notification of Message app opening

Tags: ios

Is there a public API to listen for when apple apps open? For example if a user opens up the message app can my app listen for that event?  Thank you

Comment: At a high level, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to detect if a user is sending text messages while driving and so far my research points to not being able to detect anything in the messages app.

Comment: This isn't going to be possible, due to the sandboxed nature of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If an app supports a [URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html), you can launch that app from within your own app, but there's no means of trapping an "app 'x' has launched" style system event.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such one. At least declared event.